# How to show a popup on click of Asp.Net Button click event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, popup

I have a popup which displays a message to the user which says their information has been submitted.The popup div's id NewCustomerStatusPopUp,I want this popup to be displayed when the information has been successfully inserted in the database , so how do I call the javascript function to show popup when all the information has been submitted.Can any one just let me know how can I do this.
Here is my popup

```
<div id="NewCustomerStatusPopUp">
<asp:Label ID="lblStatus" Text="" runat="server"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#NewCustomerStatusPopUp
    {
    position: fixed;
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left:-255px;
    margin-top:-150px;
    border: 10px solid #9cc3f7;
    background-color:White; 
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 102;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size: 10pt;
    border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:20px;
    -moz-border-radius:20px;

    }
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: like this [js_popup](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp)

Comment: @jflood.net I posted my popup html and css

Comment: what about your click event handler in the code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call a javascript function from server you can use a `RegisterStartipScript`:

After ur insert query  write this code

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "id", "callMyJSFunction()", true);

<script type="text/javascript">
function callMyJSFunction()
{
    alert("Record inserted sucessfully.");
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the statement , I am using it for the first time

Comment: server code to JavaScript: you can register script block to run on page like above

Comment: but I need this popup to be displayed only after my data has been saved successfully

Comment: so u have to call RegisterStartupScript after your insert query fire sucessfully.

Comment: are you asking me that , or suggesting me that I should call it after insert query.

Comment: you have to popup to be displayed only after my data has been saved successfully so u have write code of RegisterStartupScript after your insert query fire sucessfully.

Comment: thanks will try this , what is "id" in the code , could explain me the statement.

Comment: "GetType()" The type of the startup script to register. "id" is The key of the startup script to register."callMyJSFunction()" The startup script literal to register. "true" A Boolean value indicating whether to add script tags.

Comment: but it is getting displayed as soon as page is loaded.

Comment: ur insert query on button click or where

Comment: button click itself , I dont want it to be displayed every time the page loads.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got an click event handler in your code behind performing the insert, no need for JS, wrap the div in a panel:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlStatus" Visible="false" >
    <div id="NewCustomerStatusPopUp">
      <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" Text="" runat="server"/>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

In your code behind, once you've asserted that the new customer was added successfully,

set pnlStatus to visible.

```
pnlStatus.Visible = true;
```

Comment: thanks for the help , can I call the javascript function using Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock or something like that.

Comment: do you really need JS to do this?

Comment: I was planning to use Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock , that is the only reason.

Comment: ok I will try this , but what makes you think that he solution was silly , just curious.

Comment: It's over complicating a simple task. All you want to do is display something after processing an event. Using a panel that's hidden on load and setting to Visible after the customer has been inserted is perfect for this kind of thing.

Comment: I worked for me , the only issue I could see is I will have to set its visibility to false on other post backs , as it will be displayed again.